# What are the downsides to passwordless authentication?

Tags: email, security, authentication, passwords

In case of using password-backed authentication, if user forgets the password, the provider always trusts the user's email security.

So why the whole fuss? Why not use email for sending the secret login keys to registered users? Isn't that what sites do when user forgets the password?

What is the reason for still using passwords for authentication?
What are the major problems with passwordless auth that passworded auth lacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is if you log on via forgotten password, you usually have to *change* the password to something else, so it cannot be undetected - an attacker will likely be discovered. If it's just a login link in email, this is not the case, the attacker can log in, and likely nobody will notice. There can be controls to mitigate this of course, but it quickly becomes a UX question.

Another UX aspect is having to go to your email all the time if there is only a login link. A lot of people use password managers, which make entering very secure and unique passwords really easy. If it's a login link, you have to open your email, disrupting your flow in the application. It's arguably inconvenient.

Also a login link sent in an email will contain a token in the url. That will be remembered by the browser, logged in intermediate proxies, logged to the web server logs and so on. Secrets should not be sent in the url. However, if it's a one-time token valid for a (very) limited time, this risk is very much mitigated.

Having said all these, there are commercial applications that opted for passwordless login via an emailed link. If implemented correctly (a strong enough one-time token with enough entropy, generated with a proper crypto random generator and so on), passwordless login via an emailed link can be secure enough for many applications, and it's mostly a UX question (keeping in mind the security considerations above).